# Selenium: close specific tab (handle) by index without switching to it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is it possible to close a specific tab in [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) by index wihout switching to it?

Currently I am doing this:

```py
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

I found that switching tabs makes my script very unstable, so I would prefer to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is possible if using [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) but it requires to use [Chrome Developer Tools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) (which is supported in Selenium 4).

More specifically you have to:

1. Get list of targets using [Target.getTargets](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/#method-getTargets) method.
2. Extract the `targetId` of the page (target) you want to close.
3. Close the page (target) using [Target.closeTarget](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/#method-closeTarget) method passing the `targetId`.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver can close a `window/tab` instance if it has the focus on that particular `tab` or `windows`.

So you can not close a `tab or windows` if you are focusing on a different `tab` or `windows`.

If you are facing `unstable` script execution while switching `tabs/windows` I'd say have `time.sleep(2)` or `time.sleep(3)` that should help you resolve or get rid off un-stable.

Also remember, `driver.quit` would close all the instances.